# Manually entering data using Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

How can I enter data through the GUI interface rather than an `insert` command in SQL Server Management Studio 2012? I can't find it anywhere whereas there used to be an option in the previous versions. There used to be a table GUI where you could point to a certain record and add/modify date. Can't find it in 2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to add new rows by right-clicking the table that you're interested in, and then selecting `Edit Top 200 Rows`.

If required, the value for this can be increased from 200 via the tools menu: `Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Value for Edit Top <n> Rows command`.

Presumably, the reason that they limit the number of rows returned is because *this is not a robust way to manipulate data*. The risk that you'll press the wrong key and accidentally overwrite important data is quite high.

If this isn't a live, production-critical database, and you're interested in regularly working with the data in a tabular/spreadsheet view, you may want to consider linking Microsoft Access to your database.

Comment: Spot on.  Thank your for the valuable tip.  I was wondering where this option could have gone.  You're right, I don't want this for large and production database.  I just needed it for some small lookup tables and quick testing.  Many Thanks

Comment: Not spot on. Cannot find it yet.